# No values when scraping using beautiful soup (spinner & bounce rather than value)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrape new covid cases for various states from state website. When using beautiful soup to pull the total days cases I am unable to obtain the value, please help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

url = 'https://floridahealthcovid19.gov'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(covid.find('h2', attrs= {'id':'total-cases-stat'}) #neither work
print(soup.find(id='total-cases-stat'))


<h2 id="total-cases-stat">  #output
<div class="spinner">
<div class="bounce1"></div>
<div class="bounce2"></div>
<div class="bounce3"></div>
</div>
</h2>
```